# aiohttp ClientSession 'Unclosed connector'

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have an application that runs indefinitely and calls multiple external API providers all the time.
Since i keep using the same set of external API providers, i have a ClientSession for each provider that i never close.
At some point i get error

```
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fb1b3b52580>, 5134.961)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7fb1c0445d60>
```

and

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fb1c0445100>
```

as far as i understand i should reuse the client if i need it repetitively, so im not sure what im supposed to do here. since this is an application in a container i dont feel like i should worry about cleaning up because when the application terminates, the machine terminates. and also i want to have 1 client so i can reuse it, so i dont see why i should ever close the client session.

Comment: It's still preferable to close the client when exiting, and you'll continue to receive this warning if you don't. Look at the examples in the doc, and you'll see `async with` used on both the client and request.